# How to reduce boolean expression complexity?

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("foo1");
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("foo2");
Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile("foo3");
Pattern p4 = Pattern.compile("foo4");
Pattern p5 = Pattern.compile("foo5");

if (p1.matcher(kvTarif.getkey()).matches() || p2.matcher(getkey()).matches() ||
        p3.matcher(getkey()).matches() || p4.matcher(getkey()).matches() ||
        p5.matcher(getkey()).matches())
```

checkstyle says that the boolean complexity is 4 (max allowed is 3).

How can I reduce the complexity?

Comment: Does each call to `getkey()` return the same thing? You could just do `Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("foo[1-5]"); if(p1.matcher(kvTarif.getkey()).matches()) { // code ... }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reduce the number of patterns to 2, according to the logic with which you are matching:

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("foo1");
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("foo2|foo3|foo4|foo5");  // match foo2 through foo5

if (p1.matcher(kvTarif.getkey()).matches() || p2.matcher(getkey()).matches()) {
    // handle this case
}
```

As user @JonnyHenly mentioned, you could simplify the second pattern even more by using this:

```
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("foo[2-5]");
```

Comment: Wouldn't `"foo[2-5]"` be the same as `"foo2|foo3|foo4|foo5"`?

Comment: Yes, but it would also make the answer less recognizable to the person who asked it.

Comment: Or to 1, with `Pattern.compile("foo1|foo2|foo3|foo4|foo5")` or  `Pattern.compile("foo[1-5]")`, Note that these both compile to the same DFA, so there is little point in trying to 'optimize' the former as the latter.

Comment: @EJP Read his code carefully.  It is making a _different_ method call for `foo1` than the others.  So I was unable to combine them just given the tiny code snippet in the OP.